# What is the primitive of $f(x) = (x^a + b)^\frac{1}{a}$?

Tags: integration

In studying a physical problem I was stopped by an integral that can be written in this clean way
$$
\int_0^K (x^a + b)^\frac{1}{a} dx \qquad a,b \in \mathbb{R} \qquad x,K \in \mathbb{R}^+
$$
I tried with the substitution $u = x^a + b$ but it is useless, and the wolframalpha site too can't solve it. The worse is that I don't know signs of constants $a$ and $b$ (the integral itself will be exploited in determining them with the help of physical considerations, but I don't have no a priori reasons that fix they signs). I only know that $x$ and $K$ are positive. Almost surely $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ but surely $b$ is a generic real number. I don't know which way to turn. Is it solvable and anyone is interested in solving it? Thank you!

Comment: There is solution in terms of hypergeometric functions. I supposed that is not a nice news for you. But it is doable.

Comment: Of course this news sounds alarming :-) but it give a hope too. Can you say something more?

Comment: I shall be back within 10 hours from now. Here, it is 9:30pm (just as in Milano, I bet !!). I shall post some stuff tomorrow morning, be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider first the problem (for $b\neq 0$) of the antiderivative $$I(x)=\int (x^a + b)^\frac{1}{a} dx=\frac{x \left(x^a+b\right)^{1+\frac{1}{a}} 
   }{b}\, _2F_1\left(1,1+\frac{2}{a};1+\frac{1}{a};-\frac{x^a}{b}\right)$$ where appears  the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

The evaluation of $I(K)$ does not make any problem. However, for $I=0$, depending on the sign of $a$,we can have different results. Using limits, we have $$a> 0\implies I(0)=0$$ $$a<0 \implies I(0)=\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{-2/a} \,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right) \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{2}{a}\right)}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)}$$

You can find a lot of freely available subroutines for the numerical evaluation of the required function (e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Hypergeometric-Functions.html)).

**Edit**

To get rid of Pochhammer symbols, this hypergeometric function can simply write
$$_2F_1\left(1,1+\frac{2}{a};1+\frac{1}{a};t\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{a}\right)}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty \, \frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{a}+n\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}+n\right)}\,t^n$$

Comment: WOW thank you! Watching wikipedia I don't understand why they use 2 cases with Pochhammer symbol in $_2F_1$, and not simply write "1+serie starting with n=1". At the moment I'm very busy but I'll try to study what you wrote next weeks, I hope this will be useful (of course I hoped in a simpler solution :-O)